# Facebook - How do i get the count of views on a live video?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the count of viewers on my live video on Facebook.

I've tried this, as it says in the [official docs](https://graph.facebook.com/live_video_id/?fields=live_views&access_token=my_access_token).

But I get this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (live_views) on node type (Video)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "GEwo6ywtEhS"
   }
}
```

Have a look in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/) - there's a entry for live_views:

> "The instant viewer count of the live video now".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook says, you tried to get field "live_viewers" not for a Live Video, but for simply Video.
Be sure to use `live_views` only for Live Videos.
If you want to get number of views for a Video that was a Live Video before (and now became a simple video on demand), the try to use `video_insights`
(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/video_insights)